# How to "left-align" a table in the "center" of the page?

Tags: html, css

This may be a weird one:

**I have a page where I don't control the HTML, but I can inject some additional CSS**.

I have some tables which I need to align on the page. The problem is that all the other elements are aligned center on the page, but they all have fixed width. For aesthetic reasons I don't want all the tables to be of the same width, I want them to be of variable width depending on the contents.

Notice in the below code how the main container is full width on the page and the other content does not have any other wrapper elements around them. Because of this, all individual items are centered on the page using css. And also because **the main container has other full width children (that I have not shown here), I cannot make the container be of reduced width and center it**.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.content p,
.content span,
.content table {
    display: block;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class=content>
  <span>Some content header </span>
  
  <p>Some content which can be long.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac blandit nisi. Curabitur fermentum dui tortor, sed rutrum velit facilisis non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus egestas erat sapien, ac scelerisque erat rhoncus id. Nullam aliquam libero et aliquam bibendum. Curabitur porttitor lorem in libero molestie, vitae ornare lacus fermentum. Curabitur condimentum tellus fermentum, feugiat nunc dictum, commodo est.</p>
  
  <table class=table1>
    <tr>
      <td>Test Table 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <br/>
  
  <table class=table2>
    <tr>
      <td>Test table 2 which need to have more width than the first one</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I finally want looks something like this image:

[image: expected alignment]

Notice that:

1. The tables are left aligned with the rest of the items in the page.
2. The tables are of different width.

Obviously I don't want to hardcode the widths or the left margin for the tables.

Any idea if I can achieve this using just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to an outer wrapper on your table:

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Add this CSS to your table:

```
table th, table td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

The CSS above will both center your table to 80% of the screen width as well as left align all text within it.

**Update**

If you cannot center the wrapper element, use flexbox on the wrapper element instead to center all of the children.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The CSS above makes it so that any element that is a direct child of the wrapper will be centered, so all elements will be equally centered, including your table. If you want them equally spaced between each other, change `justify-content: center;` to `justify-content: space-between;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the main container has other full width children (that I have not shown here), I cannot make the container be of reduced width and center it. Added this detail to the question. My bad for not adding it initially.

Comment: Updated answer.